# Can I run one pendant light off garbage disposal switch?

Tags: electrical

I failed my electric inspection because my current over the sink pendant light fixture is run to a switch in a two-gang box that include a kitchen appliance outlet and is pulling power from the same 20 amp line. Inspector said my light fixture can't be on the same circuit as a kitchen appliance, which sounds credible. So would a solution be to run a wire to the pendant light off a new two gang box where my garbage disposal switch currently sits? If not, what else would be the solution here?

Comment: How many HP is your garbage disposal, is there anything else on that circuit as is, and is the breaker for that circuit a 15A or a 20A breaker?

Comment: @SteveSether The problem that the inspection cited is that kitchens must have at least 2 dedicated countertop circuits *and* those circuits (even if it is more than 2 of them) can't be used for lighting or anything else hardwired with a couple of very small exceptions (clock, I think ignition for a gas stove (though not 100% sure)).

Comment: @steve sether , You may be getting confused. If the garbage disposal is 3/4 Hp /120v that device is 13.8amps (table 430.248) this is then multiplied by 125% because it is a motor load or a load value of 17.25 amps. Code requires book value to be used per 430.6.A.1 & 430.22. If your disposal has a different number as they are usually smaller than book value the book value is needed so there is a big difference in the code rated total load and what the nameplate may list. It is usually the home owner that is wrong because they don’t know the code, to tell the truth some electricians don’t either

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect up any kitchen lighting to any of the dedicated small appliance circuits. And any receptacle near a counter automatically *becomes* a dedicated small appliance circuit.

The solutions include:

- New circuit - kind of crazy given the low power needed for modern LED lighting, plus the work involved.
- Connect to existing lighting circuit - that is the most logical, but not always the easiest
- Connect to a circuit in the kitchen that is not connected to any small appliance receptacles, like the garbage disposal or dishwasher. That's your idea, and it *should* work.

If I remember correctly, you can't normally have receptacles on a circuit that has 50% or more capacity used by hardwired loads. For example, if a circuit has a 10A garbage disposal or dishwasher then you can't put a regular receptacle on the same circuit. But you should be able to add more hardwired loads (like lighting) as long as the total does not exceed 80% of the capacity of the circuit (it gets a little more complicated than that, as only continuous loads (like lighting) need to be derated but not temporary loads (like a garbage disposal that runs for a few seconds at a time), but better to stay well within the capacity of the circuit).

There is another reason, aside from code compliance, to **not** put lighting on small appliance circuits: **GFCI**. The small appliance circuits require GFCI protection. Lighting generally does not, and in fact it is generally better to not have lighting GFCI protected because if it is protected and a ground fault occurs on the circuit, the lights go out! Leaving you in the dark next to a broken food processor or whatever.

Comment: I'm going to attempt to apply logic to your last (code-based) paragraph and I know I'm setting myself up for trouble... If the OP has a _single_ task light on a GFCI protected circuit with the disposal, and the disposal trips the GFCI/breaker/whatever, then, in theory, only that one bulb goes out leaving the rest of the room lighting still functioning. In that case, he may have a bit harder time seeing whether he's managed to wash all the egg off that plate, but should, otherwise, be able to see to flip necessary switches, navigate to the panel, etc, without groping in the dark, right?

Comment: Take the word any out and I would almost agree. The 2 dedicated circuits I agree but additional circuits can have lighting there is a exhibit that should assist internet only electricians 210.27 that had a nice illustration of this.  If the light goes out so would the disposal so that argument doesn't hold. As both the disposal and light require 125% if there combined wattage x 1.25 is less than the breaker size it would be code compliant.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm definitely in the category of "internet only electricians" :-) I searched a little and couldn't find a 210.27 that had to do with kitchens, but it might vary depending on NEC edition. As far disposal and light together, if under 125% no issue. But as I understand it (and please correct me if I'm wrong), that's find for "all hardwired", but if you have (for example) 12A hardwired then you can't *also* have a regular plug-in receptacle on the same circuit. Or did I misread that somewhere? Not so much applicable here as likely the opposite - hardwired light (< 1A) + either hardwired

Comment: or plug-in disposal. (Never understood plug-in for disposal - seems to be a pointless extra item since, unlike small appliances, you don't unplug a disposal to move it around, etc. Even more so for dishwashers...)

Comment: The exhibit 210.27 is an illustration I believe it has been in the last 5 or more code cycles. The pantry and dining room receptacles can also be part of these 2 required 20 amp circuits these 2 circuits can have no other other outlets (clock and stove exempt from no other). Any additional circuits can have lighting. The book shows dining room receptacles and lighting on the same circuit. Some states require all dining room and kitchen receptacles to be 20 amp circuits because during the holidays portable roasters used to be quite common. 210.52.A.4 also helps separate 210.52.A from C.

Comment: @EdBeal  Where is Exhibit 210.27? Is it from the Handbook?

Comment: RE: "50% or more capacity used by hardwired loads", 210.23(A)(2) "Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place". So that would include a plug in disposal.

Comment: Google NEC exhibit 210.27 and view images it is there in the group find the kitchen wiring , yes it is in the handbook but not bordered in blue so I would expect it in the code book also. I get the handbook as that is what inspectors use and it provides the justification for the code by the folks that wrote it. Just like fine print notes not enforceable but will keep you out of red tag territory.

Comment: Losing the sink pendant when the disposal GFCI trips is not a problem. 
 You'd need a **very** bright and bizarrely focused pendant for it to be your inside-the disposal work light.    In reality you'll use a flashlight anyway.

Comment: @jay613 I agree you would use a flashlight. The problem is if you are the only one in the kitchen and doing a load of dishes, so you turned off the other lights (why waste energy) and turned on just the one nice light directly over the sink. Which now goes out in the middle of your running the disposal...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact that's the universe telling you to go to bed. :O